# rewrite htaccess rule so if you are on `/profile?id=2` you will only see `/profile`

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is it possible to rewrite htaccess rule so if you are on `/profile?id=2` you will only see `/profile`?

When I was looking for solutions I only found how to make it be `/profile/2`.

Comment: If URL is use `/profile` then how will you get `id` in your code?

Comment: Isn't possible to hide it from the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.htaccess allows redirects. It takes the address you asked for, and routes that to a specific place. It doesn't make the user see something different from the page they're on.

So in those solutions, you are on /profile/2. And that gets routed to /profile?id=2.  It's not a case of being on one but being shown the other.

So if you're on /profile, sure you can route that to /profile?id=2 no problem. But what if your id was really 3? If you don't have that in the url you enter, .htaccess has no way to know.

More likely you would use a cookie or session variable to keep track of the user's id. Then when the visit /profile you get their id from the session not the url.